# Assign top value to scrollTop

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a project where the logo will load in the center of the page when the user comes to the website. Then, if the user scrolls down, the logo will scroll to the top and the content will follow, but, the logo will become fixed on top once it reaches top of the window. So, what I want to do is, stop the content from going to the top (because that content goes behind the logo), e.g. #Furniture is the div, that goes to top when an anchor tag with href"#Furniture" is clicked. I want to stop the div containing #Furniture at 150px (logo's height) from top of the browser. Is that possible?

Following is the code that I have used for smooth scrolling of any div to the top:

```
$(window).load(function () {
    var $root = $('html, body');
    $('a').click(function () {
        var href = $.attr(this, 'href');
        $root.animate({
            scrollTop: $(href).offset().top
        }, 500, function () {
            window.location.hash = href;
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QD8hA/)

Answer (score 0):

Use like this:

```
var top_val = $(href).offset().top; // or anything your code for getting top value
$root.animate({
        top: "+top_val+"
    }, 500, function () {
        window.location.hash = href;
});
```

Comment: I cannot assign positioning to the divs.